# How can I avoid repetition in this Laravel seeder created for a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a **blogging application in Laravel 8**.

The application gives the users roles and permissions. There is a *many-to-many* relationship between roles and permissions. For *seeding the roles_permissions table*, I have a the RolesPermissionsSeeder seeder:

```
class RolesPermissionsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
      RolesPermissions::create([
        'role_id' => '1',
        'permission_id' => '7',
      ]);

      RolesPermissions::create([
        'role_id' => '2',
        'permission_id' => '1',
      ]);

      RolesPermissions::create([
        'role_id' => '2',
        'permission_id' => '2',
      ]);

      RolesPermissions::create([
        'role_id' => '2',
        'permission_id' => '3',
      ]);
    }
}
```

#### The problem

As can be seen above, this chunk of code appears 3 times, with slight modifications:

```
RolesPermissions::create([
    'role_id' => '2',
    'permission_id' => '1',
]);
```

Using this instead did **not** work for me:

```
RolesPermissions::create([
    'role_id' => '2',
    'permission_id' => [1, 2, 3],
]);
```

#### Question

What is the easiest way to use *one* create statement for *every role_id*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$permissions = [1, 2, 3];
foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    RolesPermissions::create([
        'role_id' => '2',
        'permission_id' => $permission,
    ]);
}
```

Or

```
$permissions = [1, 2, 3];
$role = Role::find(2);
$role->permissions()->saveMany($permissions);
```

---

**Edit**

To update without `updated_at` and `created_at` user `insert()`

```
$permissions = [1, 2, 3];
foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
    DB::table('roles_permissions')->insert([
        'role_id' => '2',
        'permission_id' => $permission,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I run `php artisan db:seed --class=RolesPermissionsSeeder` but got this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `roles_permissions` (`role_id`, `permission_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 7, 2023-01-02 08:38:09, 2023-01-02 08:38:09))`, even though the only columns are _role_id_ and _permission_id_

Comment: when you use create it automatically update both created and updated time

Answer (score 1):

```
  RolesPermissions::factory(['role_id' => '2'])
    ->count(3)
    ->sequence(
        ['permission_id' => 1],
        ['permission_id' => 2],
        ['permission_id' => 3],
    )
    ->create();
```